# Kali Linux won't boot on new PC

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, hard-disk

I had an old computer running Kali Linux, running one of the latest versions. Last week i got myself a new one, changing all the parts and buying new HDD drives. But I chose to preserve my old Hard Drive with kali linux and many other important files.

As i finished connecting the old HD to my new system, I tried to boot from it. Everything was going all right until I got a message saying "Unknown chipset". Then the screen turned suddenly all black and my monitor showed something like "input error". Is this problem fixable?

If not, would I be able to recover the files from the HD and make it usable again without having to reformat it?

In the new HD and SSD I have windows 10 installed, so I don't know if I can access those files in the old HD through this OS.

Comment: Did you change your motherboard? If yes, Linux is surprised by the new chipset there, since it is counting on the one of your old mainboard. Best practice would be to just re-install Kali anew. You should wage, if it is really worth it to fiddle around trying to manually fix it instead of just performing a clean install, which a new system kind of asks for implicitly anyway.

Comment: Yeah, but if I install Kali in my new SSD (dual booting with windows) will I be able to access the files in the old HD?

Comment: If the HDD isn't broken or anything, then of course you can access it through the new Kali Linux.